# display none not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have code like this:

```
<div
    id="cover"
    style="position: absolute; max-width:70px; max-height:20px; cursor: pointer;"
    onClick="$('.cove-ke').css('display','block !none');">
    <div
        id="cover-id"
        class="cover-ke"
        style="opacity: 0;  z-index: 999999; cursor: pointer;" 
        onClick="$('.cover-ke').css('display','none !important'">
    </div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
var finished_rendering = function() {
    $(window).mousemove(function (pos) { 
        $("#cover").css('left',(pos.pageX-40)+'px').css('top',(pos.pageY-5)+'px');
    }); 
    $('#cover-id > span > iframe').iframeTracker({                 
        blurCallback: function(){
            $(window).unbind('mousemove');
            $('.cover-ke').css('display','none');
        }
    });
}
```

when u doing mouse click on div - elemets is going hide, but its not working on iphone safari. what do u think about this? how to fix it?

Comment: From your code i am not able to understand what you are doing on mousemove and on blur callback, would you explain more in detail???

Answer (score 0):

i found a crossbrowser solution in othere topic:

```
var monitor = setInterval(function(){
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
        message.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
        clearInterval(monitor);
    }
}, 100);
```